# How can I destructure an &rest argument of varying length in my elisp macro?

Tags: macros, lisp, elisp

I have a program that takes as inputs a chunk of data and a list of rules, applying both a set of standard rules and the rules given as input to the chunk of data. The size of both inputs may vary.

I want to be able to write a list of rules like this:

```lisp
(rule-generating-macro
  (rule-1-name rule-1-target
    (rule-action-macro (progn actions more-actions)))
  (rule-2-name rule-2-target
    (rule-action-macro (or (action-2) (default-action))))
  ;; more rules
 )
```

Right now, rules are more verbose -- they look more like

```lisp
(defvar rule-list
  `((rule-1-name rule-1-target
      ,@(rule-action-macro (progn actions more-actions)))
    (rule-2-name rule-2-target
      ,@(rule-action-macro (or (action-2) (default-action))))
  ;; more rules
 )
```

The latter form looks uglier to me, but I can't figure out how to write a macro that can handle a variable-length `&rest` argument, iterate over it, and return the transformed structure. Using a `defun` instead of a `defmacro` isn't really on the table because (as hopefully the example shows) I'm trying to control evaluation of the list of rules instead of evaluating the list when my program first sees it, and once you need to control evaluation, you're in `defmacro` territory. In this case, the thorny point is the `rule-action-macro` part - getting the interpreter to read that and use its expanded value has been problematic.

How can I create a macro that handles a variable-length argument so that I can write rule lists in a concise way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`defmacro` will happily accept a `&rest` argument 
(see [Defining Macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Macros.html) for Emacs Lisp and [Macro Lambda Lists](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_dd.htm) for Common Lisp).

Then you can do pretty much anything you want with it in the macro body - e.g., iterate over it. Remember, macro is much more than just backquote!

E.g.:

```
(defmacro multidefvar (&rest vars)
  (let ((forms (mapcar (lambda (var) `(defvar ,var)) vars)))
    `(progn ,@forms)))

(macroexpand '(multidefvar a b c d))
==> (PROGN (DEFVAR A) (DEFVAR B) (DEFVAR C) (DEFVAR D))
```

Comment: Okay, I think your answer is leading me towards "what I was doing before is wrong." Probably I wasn't quite grasping how to get a macro to *return* the altered structure I wanted, and thus was getting results that looked to me like "it's not working, `&rest` is just a lump I can't manipulate." I'll try your suggestion there.

Comment: The real problem that was breaking my mental model of the situation was actually somewhat different: it was that I was passing a quoted list to the macro as an argument. I'm sure you can imagine how that makes life hard. However, the way I realized that was by using your example and slowly modifying it towards my purposes. Since your answer got me where I needed to go, accepting. :)

Comment: `(progn ,@forms)... ah, this is what I need.